# Calculate percentage difference between cells based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

- I have 4 cells: Cell 1, Cell 2, Cell 3, and Cell 4
- Each of the four cells have traffic on three days: 08-July-2019, 09-July-2019, and 10-July-2019,
- I obtained the total traffic for each using the formula: `=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2)`
- For each cell, I want to calculate the difference between traffic over those three days, i.e. difference between 08-July-2019 and 09-July-2019, 09-July-2019 and 10-July-2019.

I'm trying to calculate the difference between the traffic for each cell compared to the previous day.

I can't think of a way that it can be done. How can I accomplish this? Below is an example picture

[image: cells]

Comment: What you want is unclear, can you edit your question to add a sample of the expected output? And a brief explanation of how you go to it?

Comment: Are you able to sort your data?  If you sort by Date, then by Cell, you will be able to use a formula like `=if(A2=A1,D2-D1,"")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to compare also filtering by `column A` so "Cell 1" on one day against "Cell 1" on the previous day. If that's the case, you can use the following formula on cell `E6`:

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A6,B:B,B6)/SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A6,B:B,B6-1),0)
```

Comment: @BigBen: A2:A5 don't have a previous date to compare with so there's no point of using as formula. That being said, you are completely right, if we want to remove the error. Iferror would work great. I'm going to update it so the solution is more consistent. Thanks!